# Comment le sens de « pulvériser » passe-t-il de « réduire un matériau solide en particules » à « projeter une poudre ou un liquide » ?

Tags: sens, évolution

Comment le sens de « pulvériser » passe-t-il de « réduire un matériau solide en particules » à celui de « projeter une poudre ou un liquide » ?

> [1.  Réduire un matériau solide en particules par des méthodes, le plus souvent mécaniques, qui varient selon le grain désiré.](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P5064)(Ac.9)
> [2.  Projeter une poudre ou un liquide en fines particules sur une surface, un objet.](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P5064)(Ac.9)

Comment: Bof. Dans tous les cas, on réduit à de fines particules. Solides, liquides, atomiques, moléculaires, plus grosses, plus petites, c'est tout la même chose :-)

Comment: L'eau ,en dessous de 0 °C, est solide !

Comment: La question n'est pas une question de français mais d'anglais. [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pulveriser) : **Pulvériser** : (I.A.1.) « Réduire une matière solide ou liquide en particules très fines, en poudre ou en bruine » , et (II.) «  Répandre de manière uniforme un solide pulvérulent ou un liquide en le projetant sous pression sous forme de fines particules. Synon. vaporiser. ». Quand on regarde la partie étymologie on voit que le sens de vaporiser n'est apparu qu'au 19e s. alors que l'anglais a emprunté *vaporise* au 15e s. En anglais le sens n'a pas évolué, point c'est tout.

Comment: @None C'est une question de français, car *pulvériser* est un hypernyme et sur-ensemble de "pulverise".

Comment: @user1110341 Are you using a tool to generate your questions in French or are you writing them with the help of a dictionary? Adjectives like *ébaubi* or *éberlué* makes them outlandish :-)

Comment: Note that *ébaubi* was already considered outdated and only used jocularily in 1762.

Comment: @jlliagre Voyons, l'ami jiliagre, je m'en vais te remontrer derechef! On peut bien s'esbaudir un peu tout en étant ébaubi: il y a donc bien une version 14e siècle de ChatGPT??? :-)

Comment: @Frank  «  je suis ébaubi que "pulverise" n'ait pas le sens 2 ci-dessous » est une question d'évolution de la langue anglaise. « Comment pulvériser est allé plus loin que "pulverise"? » revient à demander pourquoi le mot anglais n'a pas évolué comme le français  vu que l'anglais "pulverise" est un emprunt au français *pulvériser*. Vérifier le sens de *pulvériser* pourrait être une question de français, mais il suffit de consulter un dictionnaire pour éviter de dire que « sens 1 est impossible ici, car l'eau n'est jamais un matériau solide ! »,  qui se base sur une définition incomplète.

Comment: @None No contest.

Comment: @None Pas d'accord, la question (certes sans doute améliorable) est de savoir comment on est passé du sens 1 au sens 2 *en français*.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore la question a été passée à la tronçonneuse, mais elle contenait *"les 2 sens ci-dessous sont dissemblable. Comment combler leur lacune ?"* sous-entendu pourquoi les deux sens/comment en est-on arrivé là?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pulvériser" est emprunté du latin tardif *pulverizare* « réduire en poudre ».
*pulverizare* est dérivé de *pulvis* « poussière».

Pulveriser, c'est diviser en petits morceaux. Quand on pulvérise quelque chose, il se disperse au vent. Le sens premier de pulvériser est de réduire quelque chose en poudre, donc de rompre une intégrité pour se retrouver avec une multitude de particules.

C'est tout comme "vaporiser". Leur emploie est proche, donc les deux mots deviennent synonymes. Vaporiser peut se traduire par "spray". "Spray", c'est plutôt "envoyer petits morceaux dans l'air". Pratiquement c'est le sens de pulvériser un liquide, puisque ce liquide est projeté en fines gouttelettes.

Or, l'acte d'utiliser du" spray paint", par exemple, constitue la combinaison des deux actes. Donc, les deux verbes se concentre sur différents aspects de la même action.

---

Pulverise means break something down to tiny pieces, or fine particles. This is  exactly what happens to a liquid, when you spray it using a spray bottle.

Here's another way to construe 'pulverise'. Pulverise means to turn something into a powder. When you spray a liquid, you turn it into many tiny droplets, which is the liquid equivalent of a powder.

Answer (score 2):

"Ébaubi" -- vraiment?  In any event, you should know that you're wrong about
"pulverise" in English not having meaning number 2.  It does.  The Oxford English Dictionary says clearly:

1.b. transitive. To divide (a liquid) into minute particles; to turn into spray.

1807 -- Stroke after stroke with doubling force he plied, Foil'd the hoar Fiend and pulverized the tide. -- J. Barlow, Columbiad vi. 219

1999 - The pumps boost pressures as high as 1,350 pounds per square inch to pulverize fuel into smaller, more readily combustible bits. -- Chicago Sun-Times (Nexis) 21 June 4n

Note in particular that it's not just an old usage like your surprising "ébaubi" -- it was used by a Chicago newspaper in 1999.

So the premise of your question is wrong.  It's simply not true that "le mot anglais n'a pas évolué comme le français" in this case, since both the English and the French words DO have the second listed meaning.  Not that there'd be anything surprising in two languages' usages, metaphorical extensions (or not), etc. being different.  But this is not an example of that.

Comment: Cette réponse répond à [cette version-ci de la question](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/53992/1).

Answer (score 0):

> [**Pulvériser**] Le verbe a été repris [à partir de l'emprunt au bas latin « réduit en poussière » dérivé du latin classique avec l'idée de « poudre »] au sens de « réduire en poudre », avec une valeur affaiblie, « réduire en miettes, en petites parcelles » (milieu XVIIe s.) et, d'abord dans le langage scientifique, « projeter (un liquide) en très fines gouttelettes » (1866).
>
> [**Vaporiser**] [...] dérivé savant du latin *vapor* (1756), signifie « faire passer (une substance) de l'état liquide à l'état gazeux ». ◆ Le verbe est passé dans l'usage général (1866) au sens de « disperser et projeter en fines gouttelettes ».
>
> [**Atomiser**] emprunté (1884, *atomisé*) à l'anglais to *atomize*, de *atom* (même origine que atome) au sens non scientifique de « très petite particule » pour « réduire en particules ténues ». [...] ATOMISEUR n. m., « pulvérisateur », est emprunté (1928) à l'anglais *atomizer*, de *to atomize* [...]
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, Robert, au différentes vedettes entre crochets ]

Donc une trajectoire du sens tendant vers l'affaiblissement avec un choix de lexique en science, plutôt arbitraire ; un peu à l'opposé de « vaporiser », moins technique dans l'usage général ; les deux évolutions étant contemporaines l'une de l'autre. Avec « atomiser », un emprunt « récent », qui lui non plus ne réfère pas strictement à l'idée de transformer en atomes.

La langue est un système qui évolue dans le sens du besoin d'exprimer les réalités du jour, couramment ou techniquement, il me semble.